# android: ad coding in xml, cannot show any ads when executed

Tags: android, admob, tablelayout

i have tried adding the com.google.ads.AdView to the xml part, xml coding as follows:

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >
<TableRow
    <Button android:id="@+id/equal" 
        style="@style/Eq_button_style"
        android:text="=">   
    </Button>
</TableRow>

  <com.google.ads.AdView 
      android:id="@+id/adView"                         
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"                         
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"                         
      ads:adUnitId="a123123123123c"      //this ID is confirmed correct                   
      ads:adSize="BANNER"                         
      ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   //this ID is confirmed correct                      
      ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</TableLayout>
```

However, even though the app does not crash when it runs, there is no ads showing at the bottom. the logcat is as follows:

```
10-10 01:45:16.360: I/GATE(16797): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
10-10 01:45:16.365: D/webviewglue(16797): nativeDestroy view: 0x3ef6f0
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797): An error occurred while destroying an AdWebView:
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(WebView.java:5168)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.destroy(SourceFile:252)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at com.google.ads.internal.c$e.run(SourceFile:191)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-10 01:45:16.365: E/Ads(16797):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 01:45:16.365: I/Ads(16797): onReceiveAd()
10-10 01:45:16.460: D/dalvikvm(16797): GC_CONCURRENT freed 424K, 6% free 9580K/10119K, paused 2ms+11ms
10-10 01:45:16.460: W/Ads(16797): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <464, 708>
```

How can it be solved? The program does not force close, it can still execute but the ad just cannot show. 
Also, the last row Logcat says not enough space? how to add more space for it? i have already reserved many space for it.

Many thanks in advance!

## revised logcat:

The app can still be executed appearing without any error, but these "E" parts are there any effects on the proper execution of the app in some situation?

```
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023): An error occurred while destroying an AdWebView:
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(WebView.java:5168)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.destroy(SourceFile:252)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at com.google.ads.internal.c$e.run(SourceFile:191)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
10-11 00:52:30.330: E/Ads(10023):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is indeed:

```
W/Ads(16797): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <464, 708>
```

For that device, you'll need the entire width of the screen to show an ad in portrait. Part of the problem is the `android:padding="5dp"` on your TableLayout.

Comment: Many thanks!! the ad then pop out finally. just would further like to ask, the above is for testing, would there be any difference if it is going to be posted as free app on market? do i need to amend any coding? (like removing the test deviceID?) Also, depite the ad can be shown, the logcat still have some red "E" parts. updated the logcat as above. would this "E" affect the proper running of the app?

Comment: The `An error occurred while destroying an AdWebView:` error is an Android WebView bug being caught by the SDK and logged as an error (should be logged as warning). You should be fine here. For test ads, it doesn't matter whether you leave the test device ID code in - as it is, only emulators and your phyiscal device will get test ads. Your friend's device will get live ads with the same code. Your call on whether you want to remove the testDevices before releasing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a layout problem. 
Try this once.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/equal"
                    style="@style/Eq_button_style"
                android:text="=" >
            </Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a123123123123c"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

</LinearLayout>
```